# File Upload PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

I am new to `PHP`, and I am trying to do make a form with an upload function.
I completed this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

However, when I upload a `.png`file everything is working fine. But when I try to upload a  `.jpg` I am getting the error-message "*Invalid file*".

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Is your jpg greater than the filesize you've specified (20,000 bytes)?

Comment: check your image size.Check the same upload function with a higher size png or bmp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the following things in your source :

```
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
```

Here change 20000 to 90000 or your desired size of your image to be upload

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
```

If you are updating some more extensions add .psd, .pdf to the extension.

Note : You should create a folder called `uploads` and give it 777 Permission.

Answer (score 1):

The file size you specified is too low for .jpg files.

Try a higher value or remove the file size verification. I tested without it and had no problems.